# search tree where order doesn't matter [recepies]

Tags: algorithm

I was wondering whether there are any known algorithm that allow me to filter through k list of items where the ordering of the items doesn't matter.

For example lets say lets there are dozens of recepies to make chicken salad

x1+x2+x3+...+xk= y

```
chicken+onions+mushroom+lettuce = chicken salad
onions+mushrooms+lettuce+chicken = chicken salad
mushrooms+lettuce+chicken+onions = chicken salad 
lettuce+mushrooms+onions+chicken = chicken salad
chicken+mushrooms+onions+lettuce = chicken salad
```

so basically chicken salad can be cooked with ingredients mentioned above, but the order does not matter. So assuming those components (ingredients) make Set1 (chicken salad) are there any algorithms that allow me to match the components to sets? Where those ingredients may be part of different sets (i.e onions+mushrooms+lettuce+tuna = tuna salad). Also, I should add you can also have different amount of each ingredients so chicken+chicken+mushrooms+onions+lettuce = deluxe chicken salad

I can do an O(n) search with a load of if statements, where n is the number of sets, but I was wondering if there are efficient (or **more structured**) algorithms that can help with this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to take a list of ingredients and return the recipe they can produce?

Comment: yes exactly, so entering in mushrooms+onions+chicken+lettuce or lettuce=onions+mushroom+lettuce+chicken or chicken+mushrooms+onions+lettuce, etc would result in chicken salad

Answer (score 0):

1. Define some order in the set, for example sort ingredients alphabetically.
2. Use this sorted set as a key in database table or hash table.
3. Done.

Comment: not quite sure what you mean, if I have table from 1-n with the ingredients, 1=eggs, 2=chicken, etc how does that solve the problem of having multiple combinations equaling to one item (i.e 1+2+5 = egg salad)

Comment: Maybe I just misunderstand original question. Do you need to find all subsets (recipes) of a given subset (ingredients) or you need to find exactly equal set from the database (single recipe) given a set (ingredients)?

Comment: I updated the description, hopefully that makes it more clear.I want the latter given a set of ingredients it should equal exactly one recipe

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** Use **BitSet** and **Hash**.

**Long answer:** You have a constant number of ingredients, let's say 64. Map each string to an integer index between 0..63, i.e. onions --> 0, cheese --> 1,  mushrooms --> 2 etc. Given a list of ingredients, map each index to a Unsigned 64 bit integer, i.e. onions is the 64 bit number only 0th bit set, cheese is the 64 bit number only 1st bit set, mushrooms 2nd bit set. Given a set of ingredients, sum the corresponding UInt64 to have a single UInt64. For example the set onions+mushroom corresponds to 1+4 = 5. Construct a hash (dictionary) from UInt64 to List<Dish> i.e. 5 --> "GrilledMushroomsWithOnion"

Comment: doing this in java, also using this logic if I have 5xonions = 5 != "GrilledMushromsWithOnions"

Comment: My solution works in java and any other modern language, what is the problem? Hash is either `HashMap` or `HashTable` or something similar in Java, I don't remember. You should be able to lookup the exact name for that. BitSet is the exact name in Java but you don't need to use it either. As long as you have a table cabbage --> 13, you can calculate 1<<13, and sum the ingredients. If you are concerned about the lack of unsigned values in Java, it should not matter either.

Comment: `if I have 5xonions = 5 != "GrilledMushromsWithOnions"` Aah, so it is the case that you can add each ingredient more than once to yield a different set. You should have told that in the question.

Comment: regardless of the number of ingredients you fall into the same problem, 5+2 = 7, 6+1, 4+3, 3+3+1, etc. Its hard to distinguish the components based on number.

Comment: sorry, I'm getting confused you said ingredients are: onions --> 0, cheese --> 1, mushrooms --> 2, so did you mean 0+1+2 = OnionCheeseMushroom Dish? Where OnionCheeseMushroom Dish == 3

Comment: onions --> set 0th bit = 1.  cheese --> set 1st bit = 2. mushroom --> set 2nd bit = 4. and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The best strategy will depend on the relative size of the number of ingredients in the search (call it k) vs the number of recipes (n) vs the number of different possible ingredients.

The simplest strategy is to define a hash function on sets.  That is, a hash function which doesn't care about order.  Any commutative operation applied to the elements will work for this.  Also, sorting than hashing the list works.  Once you have this then you just store all the recipes in an associative container, and search for your particular ingredients.  With a fast hash function you get O(k) searching + some initial set up cost that will be amortized away if you do enough searches.

The problem with this approach is it doesn't find recipes that only have a subset of the ingredients you are searching for.  One option would be to run this algorithm separately for each subset of your ingredients, but that brings you to O(2^k).

It also depends what your cost model is.  If you operate like a certain company in mountain view and keep an effectively infinite number of processors around, but want to generate answers in close to real time, it might be reasonable to simply check if each recipe is possible in parallel.  This could be done very quickly (for each recipe), and in fact could easily be extended to return the number of ingredients that the recipe used from your list, allowing you to provide an ordering.